# Robot Framework Telnet Library does not open Terminal

Tags: robotframework, telnetlib

I'm using the Telnet Library of the Robot Framework to establish a remote connection, but I need the terminal to be opened, but despite having set `terminal_emulator=true` and `window_size=400x100` the RF does not open the terminal when I run the test. There is no error, the test passes, but the terminal is not open. Would anyone have an idea of what it could be?

This is what I'm doing:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     Telnet    terminal_emulation=True   window_size=400x100

*** Variable ***
${Host}   ...
${Port}   ...

*** Test Cases ***
Telnet Connection
  Open Connection    ${Host}  port=${Port}
  Login  <username>  <password>  login_prompt=Username: _________  password_prompt=Password: _________
  Close All Connections
```

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the terminal is not opened? It is only a virtual terminal. This test can very well open a terminal window, but you will not be able to see it. You can verify if the terminal is open with [write](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Telnet.html#Write) and [read](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Telnet.html#Read)

Comment: So the Telnet library doesn't open a terminal like CMD? Is it all done as if it were in the background?

Comment: I dont think so. Why do you need it opened anyway? You should be able to do anything regardless.

Comment: Are you sure you have enabled the Telnet in the "Turn Windows Feature on and off"   ?

Comment: Yes @ashtav that was the first thing that I did. :-/

Comment: Can you try it manually, to check what your doing in code is works

Comment: I already did that too @ashtav. Manually it works perfectly.